# What is the formula of the function that generalizes 1-x with concave and convex curves?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, curves

Suppose there is a function f(x,alpha) such that alpha is its parameter.
For each value of alpha I need to obtain one of the curves depicted below.

[image]

I need to know the formula of this function. The function 1-x is a special case of this function that is shown in red. The domain and range of this function is [0,1].

Any ideas?

Comment: Is $(1-x^\alpha)^{1/\alpha}$ what your are looking for? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Your formula produces convex curves for the values of alpha between 0 and 1 and concave curves for the values of alpha between 1 and infinity, right? Is there any way to change this formula such that the two ranges for convex and concave curves become equal in size? For example alpha = -infinity gives us the extreme convex curve and alpha = +infinity gives us the extreme concave curve.

Comment: Sure, just set $\alpha = e^u$, $-\infty < u < \infty$.

Comment: @MartinR I ploted these two curves:  $\left(1\ -x^{e^{-2}}\ \right)^{\frac{1}{e^{-2}}}$ and $\left(1\ -x^{e^{2}}\ \right)^{\frac{1}{e^{2}}}$. But the two curves are not symmetric with respect to $1-x$. Is there a way to obtain symmetric curves for opposite values of alpha?